# Comet message sent twice

Tags: javascript, comet, dojo, cometd, bayeux

I want to use Cometd in my project and tried the Jetty 8 version of it on a Tomcat 7 server. It works but the message is being sent twice.

To check if it had something to do with the rest of the project I set up a stand-alone project with only this functionality and I still get the message twice.

I can not find out why that might be.

There are 5 files in the project:

- pom.xml
- web.xml
- index.html
- BayeuxInitializer.java
- FormDataService.java

Here is the code for each of the files:

- web.xml

  ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
            xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
            id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
      <display-name>Sertal Vision</display-name>

      <servlet>
         <servlet-name>cometd</servlet-name>
         <servlet-class>org.cometd.server.CometdServlet</servlet-class>
         <init-param>
            <param-name>timeout</param-name>
            <param-value>60000</param-value>
         </init-param>
         <init-param>
            <param-name>logLevel</param-name>
            <param-value>3</param-value>
         </init-param>
         <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>

      <servlet>
         <servlet-name>bayeux-init</servlet-name>
         <servlet-class>ch.sertal.server.BayeuxInitializer</servlet-class>
         <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>

      <servlet-mapping>
         <servlet-name>cometd</servlet-name>
         <url-pattern>/cometd/*</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>

      <servlet-mapping>
         <servlet-name>bayeux-init</servlet-name>
         <url-pattern>/bayeux/servlet/*</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>

      <filter>
         <filter-name>continuation</filter-name>
         <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.continuation.ContinuationFilter</filter-class>
      </filter>

      <filter-mapping>
         <filter-name>continuation</filter-name>
         <url-pattern>/cometd/*</url-pattern>
      </filter-mapping>

      <welcome-file-list>
         <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>

   </web-app>
  ```
- index.html

  ```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
   <html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dojo/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         var subscription = undefined;

         dojo.addOnLoad( function () {
            dojo.require( "dojox.cometd" );
            dojo.require("dojox.timing");
            // Disconnect when the page unloads
            dojo.addOnUnload( function () {
               dojox.cometd.disconnect( true );
            } );

            var cometURL = "cometd";
            dojox.cometd.init( cometURL );

            var subscription = dojox.cometd.subscribe( "/sertal/formData", function ( message ) {
               dojo.create( "li", {
                  innerHTML:message.data.count
               }, dojo.byId( "message-list" ) );
            } );

            i = 1;
            var t = new dojox.timing.Timer();
            t.setInterval( 1000 );
            t.onTick = function() {
               dojox.cometd.publish( '/sertal/formData', { count: i++ } );
            };
            t.start();

         } );
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>

   <div>
      <ul id="message-list"/>
   </div>
   </body>
   </html>
  ```
- BayeuxInitializer.java

  ```
   package ch.sertal.server;

   import org.cometd.bayeux.server.BayeuxServer;

   import javax.servlet.GenericServlet;
   import javax.servlet.ServletException;
   import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
   import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
   import java.io.IOException;

   public class BayeuxInitializer extends GenericServlet {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = -9089442901563633963L;

      @Override
      public void init() throws ServletException {
         BayeuxServer bayeux = ( BayeuxServer ) getServletContext().getAttribute( BayeuxServer.ATTRIBUTE );

   //      new HelloService( bayeux );
         new FormDataService( bayeux, getServletContext() );

      }

      @Override
      public void service( ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse ) throws ServletException, IOException {
         throw new ServletException( "sorry :-)" );
      }
   }
  ```
- FormDataService.java

  ```
   package ch.sertal.server;

   import org.cometd.bayeux.Message;
   import org.cometd.bayeux.server.BayeuxServer;
   import org.cometd.bayeux.server.ServerSession;
   import org.cometd.server.AbstractService;

   import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
   import java.util.Map;

   /**
    * Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
    * User: micha.roon
    * Date: 1/16/12
    * Time: 12:25 PM
    * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
    */
   public class FormDataService extends AbstractService {
      private ServletContext context = null;

      public FormDataService( BayeuxServer bayeux, ServletContext context ) {
         super( bayeux, "hello" );
         this.context = context;
         addService( "/sertal/formData", "processFormData" );
         System.out.println( "New FormDataService" );
      }

      public void processFormData( final ServerSession remote, Message message ) {
         Map<String, Object> input = message.getDataAsMap();

         remote.deliver( getServerSession(), "/sertal/formData", input, null );
      }
   }
  ```
- pom.xml

  ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

      <groupId>BayeuxTest</groupId>
      <artifactId>BayeuxTest</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>

      <build>
         <plugins>
            <!--compiler plugin-->
            <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
               <configuration>
                  <source>1.6</source>
                  <target>1.6</target>
               </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
               <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
               <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>1.1</version>
               <configuration>
                  <username>${tomcat.username}</username>
                  <password>${tomcat.password}</password>
                  <url>${tomcat.manager}</url>
                  <path>${tomcat.context}</path>
               </configuration>
            </plugin>

         </plugins>
      </build>

      <dependencies>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
         </dependency>

         <!--for cometd support-->
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.cometd.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>bayeux-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.cometd.javascript</groupId>
            <artifactId>cometd-javascript-jquery</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <type>war</type>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.cometd.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>cometd-java-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
         </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlets</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.4.v20111024</version>
            <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                  <artifactId>jetty-client</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
         </dependency>

      </dependencies>
   </project>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using a normal channel (*/sertal/formData*) all published posts will be sent to all subscribed clients, in your case that's the browser itself and the Bayeux service. You will therefore receive two answers: one is your published post, the other one is the response from your service.

Solution: you don't want to `publish` your formData, you want it `deliver`ed:

```
      ...
      t.onTick = function() {
         dojox.cometd.deliver( '/sertal/formData', { count: i++ } );
      };
      ...
```

There are other solutions, e.g. using a service channel instead of the normal channel. See this [CometD FAQ Entry](http://cometd.org/node/79) for further explanations.

UPDATE:

I withheld another change necessary to make this work on my machine: `dojo.require` needs to be called outside of the `addOnLoad` handler.

```
     ...   
     dojo.require("dojox.cometd");
     dojo.require("dojox.timing");

     dojo.addOnLoad(function () {
         ...
```

I have been using dojo v1.7.1.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this was not the solution. The test page does not show any messages now.

Comment: Actually, it works over here. I had to make another little correction to the way `dojo.require` was called, I'll update my answer.